# How do I solve this problem while installing pandas on Mac?

Tags: python, pandas, pip, data-science, python-3.8

I am installing pandas with

`pip3 install pandas`

But it is installing all the dependencies of pandas, since the release. How can I install the latest one? Or is this how it usually happens?

Comment: All dependencies need to be available for pandas to work. One of the core dependency is `numpy`.

Comment: Indeed pandas needs quite a lot of other packages to work. Just have a look at `pip3 list` after the installation has finished, to to see all the new packages installed.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html#dependencies Ckeck out this Link